# Undelivered mail returned to user when sending mail from default Magento SMTP in magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2.3.2

When sending mail to a mail id after submitting contact form Undelivered mail returned to user.we are using default magento SMTP for sending mails with host smtp.sendgrid.net.Anybody know abouth the reason, Magento version is 2.3.2

Comment: Are you facing issue on local or stage?

Comment: The problem is in live server. The sender id is contact@shopname.com and the receiving id is contact@shopname.com. domain name is shop.shopname.com.using host sendgrid.net.when changing receiving id to my gamil id the mail is receiving. what will be the issue

Comment: can you pls help sir.

Comment: I am not sure but sender and receiver id should not be same, also it gives error when we fire emails from Yahoo to some other hosts some time like gmail and other domains because of rules & protocols because they are not trustworthy.

BTW Why you'r receiving and sender id is same?

Comment: it is from a contact form in the site. so it is given like this.

Comment: Yes, I understand it is from Contact Form but we should take customer's email id or you can try any other sender email id with same domain name like test@shopname.com